# how to eliminate repeated bigrams from trigrams in python nltk

Tags: python, nltk

I have generated bigrams, trigrams in different files.

Now I have bigrams as below.

```
high cpu
power supply
nexus 7000
..
```

Now I have trigrams as below.

```
high cpu due
power supply failure
..
```

There is possibility that for few phrases only bigrams are generated and trigrams may not give much meaning. But for few phrases like `"high cpu due"` the trigrams have much more meaning than bigrams.

So I want to eliminate the repeated bigrams which are already present in trigrams and retain only the bigrams which are not present in trigrams. I tried with the below code, its finding the bigrams present in trigrams but if not found its not giving the bigram back.

```
terms=['ios zone','ios zone firewall']
phrases = [
    z for z in terms if z not in [x for x in terms for y in terms if x in y and x != y]
]
print (phrases)
```

this returns `['ios', 'zone', 'firewall']`
but if there is no match then it should return bigrams

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you want to keep only bigrams that are not contained in any of the trigrams. One approach is to check for substring matches:

```
bigrams = [
    "high cpu",
    "power supply",
    "nexus 7000"
]

trigrams = [
    "high cpu due",
    "power supply failure"
]

new_bigrams = [b for b in bigrams if all(b not in t for t in trigrams)]
print(new_bigrams)
#['nexus 7000']
```

We build `new_bigrams` using a list comprehension that only adds bigrams if they are not contained in any of the trigrams. `all(b not in t for t in trigrams)` returns `False` if the bigram is a substring of any of the trigrams.

Answer (score 0):

To add up to @pault answer.

When you run a finder, you get the trigrams/bigrams as a list of lists of strings.

In order for @pault technique to work, you have to join those lists, such as:

```
bigrams = finder.nbest(bigram_measures.pmi, 200)
trigrams = tfinder.nbest(trigram_measures.pmi, 200)
trigrams= [" ".join(t) for t in trigrams]
bigrams= [" ".join(b) for b in bigrams]
```

And finally, @pault answer:

```
bigrams= [b for b in bigrams if all(b not in t for t in trigrams)]
```